# Sort data stream and pick top items in NODEJS

Tags: node.js, arrays, data-structures

I am new to nodeJS, and finding it difficult to get the best approach here. I have use case, I am getting data from a stream event of 4 seconds with different stocks(example below). Now I need to sort them and get the element based on condition(ex. **getTop(), getTop(2), getBottom(), getBottom(2)**).

data is coming as below,

1st.

{
name: Apple,
price: 1000
}

2nd.

{
name: Meta,
price: 1500
}

3rd

{
name: MICROSOFT
price: 1200
}

Now I need to sort them when I get the data every time and pick the stocks based on condition.
If I use Array here, array can be slower when it grows and I need to sort every time for the new element.

What is the best solution here, do I need to use Data Structure, if Yes which one I have to choose, Please help me on this.

Comment: You have given four examples of what you need to get. Are there only `getTop` and `getBottom`. Anything else? Is the argument any integer? Could it be `getTop(1000)`? What would be the return value of `getTop`. What will you be sorting by? Price?

Comment: @trincot, Yes need to pass interger, if I call getTop(5) I need to get the top 5 stocks, if I call getTop() it should give the topmost stock.

Comment: Any other functions? Any maximum to the argument given to `getTop`?

Comment: @trincot if no argument it should pick the top stock.
can you please suggest some nodeJS solution?

Comment: Sorry, that was not my question. Are there any other functions besides `getTop`? Is there a maximum integer that can be passed as argument, or is something like `getTop(100000)` a possible request?

Comment: @trincot, Sorry, Yes we can, but for now, we can restrict to 100.

Comment: Are there any other functions?

Comment: @trincot no same we can do for getting bottom stocks also like getBottom(10).

Comment: How large is your dataset?

Comment: @trincot That I can't tell, but I am looking for a scalable approach.

Comment: @trincot Every 2 seconds I am getting data from the stream.

Comment: But at some point you'll get a new quote for the same asset, right? What then?

Comment: @trincot, that time need to replace the old one and sort based on values.

Comment: That is an important requirement to mention in your question. How many diffetent assets exist?

Comment: @trincot sorry I missed it, random values will come from the stream, for testing we can consider 20 different stocks.

Comment: If there are so few different stocks, then your array will never have more than 20 entries. In that case the best thing is to always call `sort`. This should be fast. If your experience is that it is not fast, then please focus your question on that, providing your code, the input, ...etc, so we can check what is causing the performance issue.